# React Pages Load white page

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, pageload

My react app loads from github with the screen being all white with some of the home page visible like a silhouette once I click the home nav link the page loads the actual homepage properly. I'm not sure what the issue is, any assistance trying to figure out why this only happens with github and not in the development server would be appreciated. here is a link to the page --> https://brandonawilliams1.github.io/brandon-profile/
[react app hosted on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ukEh.png)

Here is the link to my repo. https://github.com/brandonawilliams1/brandon-profile.git

I've tried adjusting the homepage in the package.json file, and I tried changing the routes but it seems that github isn't grabbing the css for the home page

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file, you forgot to actually load your index.js script, which in turn causes the entire page to not load since the browser only receives an html file with a single div.